Stop process from another process
Hi guys I have two different processes running at the same time.
I'm trying to stop the other process which i have named loop_b
but I have only managed to stop the current process and the other doesn't stop
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import sys 


counter=0

def loop_a():
    global counter
    while True:
        print("a")
        time.sleep(1)
        counter+=1
        if counter==10:
            print("I want to stop the loop_b")
            sys.exit()
            #Process(target=loop_b).close()  -> Also i tried this but not worked

def loop_b():
    while True:
        print("b")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=loop_a).start()
    Process(target=loop_b).start()



You need to save the Process object in a shared variable, then use .kill() to stop it.

@Barmar aren't Process objects extremely difficult to share via anything like Manager or sharedctypes? I would just start loop_b first, wait for it to have a valid pid in main, then pass the pid to loop_a as an arg to be used with os.kill(pid, sig). The pid being just an int makes it much easier to share.

One possible solution could be using multiprocessing.Event synchronization primitive to signal other process that it should exit, e.g.:
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Event, Process


def loop_a(evt):
    counter = 0

    while True:
        print("a")
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            print("I want to stop the loop_b")
            evt.set()  # <-- set the flag to be True to signal exit
            sys.exit()


def loop_b(evt):
    while not evt.is_set():
        print("b")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    evt = Event()

    p1 = Process(target=loop_a, args=(evt,)).start()
    p2 = Process(target=loop_b, args=(evt,)).start()

Prints:
a
b
a
b
a
b
I want to stop the loop_b  # <-- and the loob_b ends here too


Thank you very much for the example with this I have managed to stop both processes and learn something new.
Best regards
